# download csv to browser downloads node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, download, fast-csv

I have this code:

```
    fs = require("fs");
  var downloadData = "select * from PRODUCTS"
    ibmdb.open(req.session.ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(downloadData, function (err, rows) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }


          const ws = fs.createWriteStream("productsDownloaded.csv");
          const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
          console.log("jsonData", jsonData);
          fastcsv
            .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
            .on("finish", function() {
              console.log("Write to productsDownloaded.csv successfully!");
            })
            .pipe(ws);


    
            var value = true;

            res.render("edit-products", {
              page_title: "edit-products",
              data: rows,
              userName: req.session.username,
              FN: req.session.firstname,
              LN: req.session.lastname,
              CO: req.session.company,
              value: value,
            });

          conn.close(function () {
            console.log("closing function p1 of delete product");
          });
        });
      });
```

however, it downloads but it doesn't go anywhere. So when im testing locally it goes into my vs code directory, but i want it to download by the browser, so do i have to send something to the front end? Like if i press the download button and trigger this function, it should download to the users directory. how can i achieve this?

Comment: You're calling `res.render` currently, so this code creates the response to a GET request for some web page URL, i.e. sends back an HTML document. You need to create a separate route handler with a different URL, then send back the CSV data instead (res.send(), res.file(), res.json(), etc)

Comment: @ChrisG i see. but even doing .send, or res.file, i need to send the csv downloaded to the client. what would i send through to?

Comment: First of all you're creating a JSON file, not a CSV file. Also, I have no idea what that means. The code above is probably wrapped in a route handler. For instance in express you would do `app.get("/edit-products", (req, res) => { ... });` and call res.render(...) inside, and it looks like that's what you're doing. Serving a download is something you do *instead* of res.render() (which sends back an HTML document). So you need a second `app.get("/some-download-route-here", ...)` and in there, load the data, then use `res.json(...)` to send it back.

Comment: Then you put a link like `<a href="/some-download-route-here">download</a>` on your page.